# How to add the items to an array of items using blue print

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I want to push the Geographic Coordinates to the Coordinates Array,

Coordinates Array `is an array of type` Geographic Coordinates

When using this following blueprint, every time the coordinates are pushed to the [0] location, however, I want to add to the end of the array.

How can I add the items to an array using a blueprint?

Basically, I want to `Append`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Containers are always valid in Blueprint. You don't have to assign to them to make them a valid value (opposed to Object References which are not valid by default). So setting an array by creating a new one is not needed and I wouldn't recommend doing it.

Instead of assigning a new array to the setter, you can simply get the array variable and then call [`Add`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/Array/Add/) or [`AddUnique`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/Array/AddUnique/) on it. If you have more than one entry to add, you can either add it in a for loop by iterating of the incoming array and adding it to the target array one by one or by using [`AppendArray`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/Array/AppendArray/).

If you want to ensure that the array is cleared, you call [`Clear`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Utilities/Array/Clear/) on the array to reset its contents to an empty state.